# resample() by PeriodIndex using kind parameter

Tags: pandas

The `resample()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) says that there is a `kind` parameter that will allow one to resample by a `PeriodIndex`. Does this mean I can resample based simply on a month?

#### Example

Let's say I have a Series `df`:

```
period
1    1.0
2    2.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    6.0
```

Should I be able to resample using code similar to:

```
df.resample('M', kind='period').first().fillna(0)
```

To get:

```
period
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    0.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    6.0
```

#### Additional Complexity

If `df` was:

```
period
6    6.0
```

Could I write my `resample()` code to get:

```
period
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    6.0
```

**NOTES:**

- The code I wrote does not work, but I think it's because my assumptions about `resample()` and `PeriodIndex` are incorrect.
- All periods are in the same year, so in theory, I can make a `datetime`, but I'm trying to do this by period if possible.

Comment: This is a bit confusing what datatype is your original df?  Float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depicted DataFrame in the question does not appear to have a `PeriodIndex`.  So it appears that you are hoping to have it convert to a `PeriodIndex` by `.resample(kind=)`.

You will wind up with `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'freq'` because the resampler is looking for the index type to have frequency which the ordinal index shown in the question does not.

Here is a fully working example outlining how `.resample()` functions in general, while using a `PeriodIndex`.

Once your DataFrame has the appropriate index type, you generally shouldn't be worrying about the type.  The framework usually deals with that part.  So below, you can see the resample frequencies are simply passed in.

`DataFrame.resample()` will not create that which is not there for resampling.  A small trick is to insert an index where you wish resampling to start.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print (pd.__version__)

pidx = pd.period_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2019-06-01', freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pidx,data={'period':[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]})

# knock out 2019-03
df = df.drop(df.index[2])

df = df.resample('M').first().fillna(0)
print(df)

# knock out preceding periods
df = df.drop(df.index[:-1])

df = df.resample('M').first().fillna(0)
print(df)

# preceding period to reconstitute resamples
df.loc[pidx[0]] = np.nan
df = df.resample('M').first().fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about the `PeriodIndex` – thank you for making it clear for me