# resample() over MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

#### Starting Point

I have a DataFrame `df` which has a three-level MultiIndex. The innermost level is a datetime.

```
                                   value    data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
id_1     id_2  effective_date                                            
ADH10685 CA1P0 2018-07-31       0.000048  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
               2018-08-31       0.000048  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
         CB0N0 2018-07-31       4.010784  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-08-31       2.044298  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
         CB0P0 2018-07-31      22.389493  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-08-31      23.600726  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-09-30      45.105458  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-10-31      32.249056  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-11-30      60.790889  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-12-31      46.832914  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
```

You can recreate this DataFrame with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_1': ['ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685','ADH10685'],\
               'id_2': ['CA1P0','CA1P0','CB0N0','CB0N0','CB0N0','CB0N0','CB0N0','CB0P0','CB0P0','CB0P0','CB0P0','CB0P0','CB0P0'],\
               'effective_date': ['2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31'],\
               'value': [0.000048, 0.000048, 4.010784, 2.044298, 11.493831, 13.929844, 21.500490, 22.389493, 23.600726, 45.105458, 32.249056, 60.790889, 46.832914],\
               'data_1': [17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701,17901701],\
               'data_2': ['3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra','3mra'],\
               'data_3': ['Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual','Actual'],\
               'data_4': [198.00, 198.00, 0.01, 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03]})
df.effective_date = pd.to_datetime(df.effective_date)
df = df.groupby(['id_1', 'id_2', 'effective_date']).first()
```

#### Desired outcome

The date range I am interested in is `2018-07-31` to `2018-12-31`. For each combination of `id_1` and `id_2`, I want to resample on value.

For `('ADH10685', 'CA1P0')`, I want to get `0` values from September to December. For `CB0N0`, I want to set September to `0`, and for `CB0P0`, I want to change nothing.

```
                                   value    data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
id_1     id_2  effective_date                                            
ADH10685 CA1P0 2018-07-31       0.000048  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
               2018-08-31       0.000048  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
               2018-09-30       0.000000  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
               2018-10-31       0.000000  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
               2018-11-30       0.000000  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
               2018-12-31       0.000000  17901701   3mra  Actual  198.00
         CB0N0 2018-07-31       4.010784  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-08-31       2.044298  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-09-30       0.000008  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
               2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.01
         CB0P0 2018-07-31      22.389493  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-08-31      23.600726  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-09-30      45.105458  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-10-31      32.249056  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-11-30      60.790889  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
               2018-12-31      46.832914  17901701   3mra  Actual    0.03
```

#### What I've tried

I've asked a couple of questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287911/resample-by-periodindex-using-kind-parameter) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304005/resample-dataframe-for-one-series-while-copying-values-of-all-other-series-in) related to this subject, so I have a sense of how to set the upper and lower limits for the dates and how to resample while keeping the non-`value` Series intact.

I have developed the following code, which works if I hardcode slicing each level.

```
min_date = '2018-07-31'
max_date = '2018-12-31'

# Slice to specific combination of id_1 and id_2
s = df.loc[('ADD00785', 'CA1P0')]

if not s.index.isin([min_date]).any():
    s.loc[pd.to_datetime(min_date)] = np.nan
if not s.index.isin([max_date]).any():
    s.loc[pd.to_datetime(max_date)] = np.nan
s.resample('M').first().fillna({'value': 0}).ffill().bfill()
```

I am looking for guidance on is how to best go through a large DataFrame and apply the logic to each pair of `(id_1, id_2)`. I am also looking to clean up my sample code above to be more efficient.

Comment: Can you `.to_dict()` a relevant portion of your DataFrame so I don't have to build it on my side to play around  with it?

Comment: I will post something to recreate the DataFrame, but you should be able to read it with the `.read_clipboard()` function in Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html

Comment: Learn something new everyday!

Comment: 0.24.2 getting hung up on the multiindex on copy_clipboad().

Comment: I added code that lets you recreate it easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, reindex each group of `id_1`, `id_2`  by `dt`.

```
dt = pd.date_range('2018-07-31', '2018-12-31', freq='M')

df = (df.reset_index()
        .groupby(['id_1', 'id_2'])
        .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('effective_date').reindex(dt))
        .drop(columns=['id_1', 'id_2'])
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'effective_date'}))
```

Then fill missing values in the column value.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(0)
```

Fill the remaining missing values.

```
df = df.groupby(['id_1', 'id_2']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill(axis=0).bfill(axis=0))
```

Set `id_1`, `id_2`, effective_date back to index.

```
df.set_index(['id_1', 'id_2', 'effective_date'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Why does `apply` seem to add an additional `id_1` and `id_2`?

Comment: @GoodLuckGanesh groupby object returns a dataframe of each group which includes all columns.

Comment: And after using .set_index, every group has to return new df with the new index.

Comment: I see, so using an aggregate function with `groupby` will automatically remove the index columns? when I replace `apply()` with `mean()` or `sum()`, I don't get two columns for `id_1` and `id_2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reindex()` to pick up the missing months:

```
# create the MultiIndex based on the existing df.index.levels
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)

# run reindex() with the new indexes and then fix Nan `value` column
df1 = df.reindex(midx).fillna({'value':0})

df1                                                                                                                 
#Out[41]: 
#                                   value      data_1 data_2  data_3  data_4
#id_1     id_2  effective_date                                              
#ADH10685 CA1P0 2018-07-31       0.000048  17901701.0   3mra  Actual  198.00
#               2018-08-31       0.000048  17901701.0   3mra  Actual  198.00
#               2018-09-30       0.000000         NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
#               2018-10-31       0.000000         NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
#               2018-11-30       0.000000         NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
#               2018-12-31       0.000000         NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
#         CB0N0 2018-07-31       4.010784  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
#               2018-08-31       2.044298  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
#               2018-09-30       0.000000         NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
#               2018-10-31      11.493831  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
#               2018-11-30      13.929844  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
#               2018-12-31      21.500490  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.01
#         CB0P0 2018-07-31      22.389493  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.03
#               2018-08-31      23.600726  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.03
#               2018-09-30      45.105458  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.03
#               2018-10-31      32.249056  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.03
#               2018-11-30      60.790889  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.03
#               2018-12-31      46.832914  17901701.0   3mra  Actual    0.03

# select columns except the 'value' column
cols = df1.columns.difference(['value'])

# update the selected columns with ffill/bfill per groupby on level=[0,1]
df1.loc[:,cols] = df1.loc[:,cols].groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('ffill')
```